# Why doesn't Ubuntu repos for Aarch64, ARM, PowerPC have debugging symbols?

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to get kernel debug symbols for architectures like Aarch64, ARM and PowerPC on qemu; but it seems like the repositories don't have kernel debug symbols. Why aren't there packages that have kernel debug symbols for these architectures? From what I see, it seems like debug symbols are made available for i386 and ia64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is obviously because Ubuntu [supports only amd64 and i386 architectures](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SupportedArchitectures) for desktop and server.